# Can Azure sql db service be the target of a VPN tunnel?

Tags: azure-sql-database, vpn, azure-vpn

Alistair Board
 Our vendor says "A VPC in our AWS based app will give you an IP range in the RFC 1918 address space, which means it's not internet routable  so you have to create a VPN tunnel to your SQL database" - if our SQL database is Azuredb service can we please ? :-)
The response I got to the original question was very helpful and led to Express routes as a possible approach :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Azure feedback site, it was in work back in February. I did not hear about in the public preview or production.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/5537689-allow-sql-database-to-join-virtual-network-vpn

I think you could ask Guy Haycock (in the topic above) to enroll your customer into private preview of that functionality.

Comment: Thank you for that very helpful response - so the answer is "sometime soon"  - so maybe we use Amazon  RDS db service  for now and come back to MS Azure DB Service when it's ready :-)

Comment: Just an update: the latest update is februari 9th, 2017 and it is still in the works. If it is done, I'll update this qa.